# Using a base table with composite key using columns and constant values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm stugggling to model the following schema below in EF:

[image]

`TEntity` contains a record for each TFile: `EntityId` is the `FileId` and `EntityType` is a constant value that represents a `TFile` record - there are also other tables that work this way.

`TEntityFile` is a look-up table, I've managed to model this but have included it to demonstrate the different ways I'm having to configure/use `TEntity`.  This table will store look ups of different entities to their files.

My current configuration:

```
// TEntity
EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> entityConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>()
    .ToTable("TEntity")
    .HasKey(x => x.EntityGuid);

// TFile
EntityTypeConfiguration<TFile> fileConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<TFile>()
   .ToTable("TFile")
   .HasKey(x => x.FileId);

// TEntityFile
EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityFile> entityFileConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<TEntityFile>()
    .ToTable("TEntityFile")
    .HasKey(x => new { x.EntityGuid, x.FileId });

entityFileConfig
    .HasRequired(x => x.File)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.FileId);

entityFileConfig
    .HasRequired(x => x.Entity)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.EntityGuid);
```

As each `TFile` is a `TEntity` I'd like to model the class that way:

```
public class TFile : TEntity { }
```

My problem lies with telling EF how `TFile` has a relationship with `TEntity` considering that it maps using these fields:

- FileId = EntityId
- EntityType = 1

In the queries it generates it expects a column `EntityGuid` on `TFile` to join on to.  Can I use EF in this way to model this schema? If so, what do I need to change in order for EF to know how to join a `TFile` row with its corresponding `TEntity` row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is your DB schema is not normalized and you can't create the conceptual model you describe with the DB schema as shown:

- The DB schema allows N:N relationships between `TEntity` and `TFile` 
  while your description makes it seem like you want a `1:0..1` relationship - unless you have unique constraints on each individual PK field of `TEntityFile`, but why have the table at all, then?  EF conceptual models are also not aware of unique constraints (at least in EF6 and under) and thus you couldn't create the conceptual model you desire even with the unique constraints.
- The database is not normalized due to duplication of data between
  `TEntity.EntityId` and `TEntityFile.FileId` which can lead to
  insert/update/deletion anomalies (e.g. you can update
  `TEntity.EntityId` but not delete/modify the corresponding
  `TEntityFile` record) - I believe this violates [2NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form)

Based on your description, it sounds like you want Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) inheritance with `EntityType` as your discriminator (TPH violates [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), btw, but many consider it acceptable) but you would need a separate FK field for each defined type (e.g: `EntityId` would be replaced with a `FileId` field for `EntityType == 1`).

Another route would be to use Table-Per-Type (TPT) inheritance - this obviates the need for an `EntityType` discriminator column but [could reduce performance if joining from `TEntity` to `TFile` and other inherited entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/08/17/performance-considerations-when-using-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx).

Comment: I see, I think I'll adjust to normalise the schema.  Thanks for the reply and also insight into 2NF and 3NF which had never crossed my path before.

Comment: One way you could get round this is by using a view that joins the tables then referencing that.

Comment: There are any number of ways it could be done, but many of those ways creates the real possibility of errors or simply confusion that will make your 'solution' difficult to understand by others who may need to support it in the future.  The database schema as described is flawed and if you have the power to design it properly, you should.  Sometimes we're handed an existing DB we have no control over and then we need to get creative to work with it.